# Avaliação de expressões condicionais em Java

Tags: java, compilação

Andei observando que as expressões condicionais em Java que são formadas apenas por literais ou constantes (ou operações entre eles) são avaliadas de maneiras diferentes. Sendo assim, o código abaixo compila normalmente:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (true) {
            System.out.println("teste");
        }
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("teste");
        }

    }
}
```

Porém, o este outro trecho não compila. O compilador reclama de "Unreachable code" somente na parte do `while`, sendo que a parte dentro do `if` também é "unreachable".

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (false) {
            System.out.println("teste");
        }
        while (false) {
            System.out.println("teste");
        }

    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que "unreachable codes" dentro de blocos `if` como no exemplo acima sejam tratados também como erros em tempo de compilação. Alguém sabe de alguma flag que posso passar pro compilador para isso acontecer? (se é que essa flag existe) Ou um mecanismo parecido?

Answer (score 3):

Ocorre que há uma otimização feita pelo compilador que identifica realmente que o código dentro do IF não será executado, porém escolhe apenas omití-lo e não gerar um erro de "unreachable code".
Esse tratamento diferenciado em relação ao laço WHILE é útil, principalmente para que programadores possam definir "flags" de DEBUG e RUNTIME:

```
static final boolean DEBUG = false;
if (DEBUG) {
...
...
...
}
```

A condição acima seria impossível se o compilador decidisse lançar erros de "unreachable code", ao invés de omitir o código dentro do IF quando não for DEBUG

Referência: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21

Answer (score 2):

Não creio que o [compilador `javac` tenha alguma opção para isto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Contudo, neste caso, o recomendável é usar pelo menos uma (pode ser mais) das ferramentas de análise estática do código, tais como: [Checkstyle, PMD e Findbugs](http://continuousdev.com/2015/08/checkstyle-vs-pmd-vs-findbugs/).

Realizar análise estática significa varrer o código-fonte ou bytecode procurando por erros comuns, sintaxe incorreta e riscos de bugs.

Se o projeto usa [Maven](http://luizricardo.org/2014/06/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-maven-para-gerenciar-suas-dependencias-e-seus-projetos-java/), Gradle ou alguma outra ferramenta para fazer o *build*, pode integrar a análise no processo para que ela seja executada automaticamente e gere erros caso alguma regra seja quebrada.

IDEs como Eclipse e IntelliJ possuem plugins capazes de integrar a análise com essas ferramentas e, por si só, também são capazes de executar algumas análises. Em geral, essas IDEs possuem configurações para aumentar o nível do problema de um aviso (*warning*) para um erro, forçando o desenvolvedor a corrigir o problema.

Entretanto, enquanto uma IDE funciona bem para o desenvolvimento individual, equipes geralmente precisam de um processo padrão, possivelmente com [integração contínua](http://luizricardo.org/2015/05/deploy-e-integracao-continua/), portanto a solução recomendada é usar uma ferramenta como Maven ou Gradle aliada às demais ferramentas de análise citadas acima.